# List does not have attribute reshape

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

In the code given below I am getting an error on the last line that list has attribute of reshape

cal should be a numpy array but cal.reshape is giving the error . Also while printing cal I am getting 13 element array but a 4 element array was expected which will be the sum of elements along the rows .

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[56.0,0.0,4.4,68.0],

[1.0,2.0,104.0,52.0,8.0],

[1.8,135.0,99.0,0.9]])

cal=A.sum(axis=0)

print(cal)

percentage=100*A/cal.reshape(1,4)
```

`cal` should be a numpy array but `cal.reshape` is giving the error . Also while printing `cal` I am getting 13 element array but a 4 element array was expected which will be the sum of elements along the rows .

Comment: What is your expected output of `cal`?

Comment: Shouldn't `A` be a matrix?

Comment: The wierd behaviour is because not sublists are of the same size in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see carefully, your 2D list `A` has 5 elements in the second row instead of 4 like the other rows, and that causes issues with `np.sum`, since numpy assumes a homogeneous array where all sublists have equals rows.

So you would need to either remove an element from the 2nd list like so, (In below example I removed the first element) to make your array 3x4

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[56.0,0.0,4.4,68.0],

[2.0,104.0,52.0,8.0],

[1.8,135.0,99.0,0.9]])

cal=A.sum(axis=0)

print(cal)

percentage=100*A/cal
print(percentage)
```

And the output comes out as

```
[[93.64548495  0.          2.83140283 88.42652796]
 [ 3.34448161 43.51464435 33.46203346 10.40312094]
 [ 3.01003344 56.48535565 63.70656371  1.17035111]]
```

Or you can add extra 0's in the first and third row and reshape your array to (1,5)

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[56.0,0.0,4.4,68.0, 0],

[1.0, 2.0,104.0,52.0,8.0],

[1.8,135.0,99.0,0.9, 0]])

cal=A.sum(axis=0)

print(cal)

percentage=100*A/cal
print(percentage)
```

The output here will be

```
[[ 95.23809524   0.           2.12150434  56.24483044   0.        ]
 [  1.70068027   1.45985401  50.14464802  43.01075269 100.        ]
 [  3.06122449  98.54014599  47.73384764   0.74441687   0.        ]]
```

Comment: What answer are you looking for @Math_Zombie ? Can you update the question with that

Comment: but still if I not use reshape function and divide by just cal , I get the same result – Math_Zombie

Comment: I just checked and if you do `percentage=100*A/cal`, the code works and result is the same, is that not what you want @Math_Zombie ! What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 2nd row has 5 elements instead of 4. If you correct this error your script will work.

Comment: that was such a silly mistake , also If I dont use reshape function it gives the same result , is reshape important

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh but still if I not use reshape function and divide by just cal , I get the same result